# Как создать базу данных SQLite без rowid?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Менеджер SQLite от FireFox при добавления полей в таблицу автоматически создает поле с rowid какое в моем случаем совсем не нужно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Удивитесь, но [это написано в документации к SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html): надо в `CREATE TABLE` указать...

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wordcount(
  word TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  cnt INTEGER
) WITHOUT ROWID;
--^^^^^^^ ^^^^^ вот это
```

У этого есть масса плюсов и минусов, которые расписаны там же. Самое важное:

- В таблице без `rowid` должен быть **первичный ключ**.
- `AUTOINCREMENT` **не будет работать**.
- `sqlite3_update_hook()` на таблицы без `rowid` **работать не будет**.
- Таблица будет устроена **проще**, поскольку не будет иметь обязательного индекса с `rowid`, некоторые виды поиска будут быстрее.